# Value of an algebric expression in a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

I came across such a problem:

Given the equation
\begin{equation}
x^2 + \sqrt{m} x + n = 0        .\tag{1}
\end{equation}
If it has two equal real roots, what is the value of $(m+1)(m-1) - 2(2n - 1)$?

This is what I have done:
Since the quadratic equation has two equal roots, we have
\begin{equation}
m - 4n = 0   ,\tag{2}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
m = 4n        .\tag{3}
\end{equation}
However,
\begin{equation}
(m+1)(m-1) - 2(2n - 1) = m^2 - 4n + 1          ,\tag{4}
\end{equation}
I tried many ways to manipulate eq. (4), but couldn't figure out its value. I don't know how eqs. (2) or (3) can help. Is there any way out?

Comment: The $+1$ in (4) should be $+2$. Then simply substitute for $m$ using (3), The resulting expression in $n$ is your answer.

Comment: The +1 is -1+2. I agree that you get an expression in only one of the parameters ($m$ or $n$).

Comment: All you can deduce is $m>4n$ from the condition of real roots. That gives you $m^2-4n+1>16n^2-4n+1=(4n-(1/2))^2+(3/4).$ But I don't see how you solve the question without additional information.

Comment: @MariusS.L. The condition is two *equal* real roots.

Comment: @Bonnaduck 's answer is correct. There is no further simplification.

Comment: @Bonnaduck Thanks, I missed that. Then my inequality will be equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
(m+1)(m-1)-2(2n-1)&=m^2-1-4n+2\\
&=m^2-4n+1\\
&=m^2-m+1
\end{align*}

There's no way to further "solve" this problem. There are infinitely many values for $m$ that satisfy the given conditions.

It should be noted that if we are working with a polynomial over the reals, then we must also add the condition that $m\geq 0$, since $\sqrt\cdot$ cannot input negative values.